# Hibernate @Embeddable behavior secondary table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a very simple project with 3 classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A", uniqueConstraints = {})
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "A", indexes = {})
@SecondaryTable(name = "C", pkJoinColumns {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(columnDefinition = "A_ID", name = "A_ID")})
public class Machine
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "A_ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "a1", nullable = false)
    private Integer a1;

    @Column(name = "c1", table = "C", nullable = false)
    private Integer c1;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")})
    private List<B> bs = new ArrayList<B>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@SecondaryTable(name = "A_B", pkJoinColumns = {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(columnDefinition = "B_ID", name = "B_ID")})
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "B")
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "B_ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "B_1", nullable = false)
    private Integer b1;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
@AttributeOverride(name = "d1", column = @Column(name = "D_1", table = "A_B")),
@AttributeOverride(name = "d2", column = @Column(name = "D_2", table = "datastore_assignment"))})
    private final D d = new D();

    }

@Embeddable
public class D
{
    private long d1;

    private long d2;
}
```

When inserting into the session one A instance with two B I would expect this:

```
A_B table
A_ID   B_ID   D_1   D_2
   1      1     1     1
   1      2     1     1
```

But this the thing is:

```
A_B table
A_ID   B_ID   D_1   D_2
   1      1     0     0
   1      2     0     0
   1   NULL     1     1
   1   NULL     1     1
```

Any idea?

Thank you!

Regards.

ssedano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that A does not know of D_1 and D_2 and doesnt insert them. And hibernate does not care that the link table and the secondary table are the same and inserts into it D_1/D_2 when saving B. To resolve that:

add inverse to tell A it should not insert into A_B because it does not know of D_1 and D_2

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = ...)
@JoinTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")})
private List<B> bs = new ArrayList<B>();
```

and map the reference to A in B

```
@ManyToOne(name = "B_1", nullable = false, table = "A_B")
private A a;
```

make sure you set

```
a.getBs().Add(b);
b.setA(a);
```

Comment: What package is @Inverse? Thanks

Comment: uh sorry, in JPA it is mappedby i think